# My JS Function that displays a block of HTML after pressing an OnClick button is buggy

Tags: javascript, html, function, button

I have a JS function that works with a button; basically, it's supposed to show the HTML code after clicking the button. However, for some reason, when I load the page, the HTML is visible before clicking the button; clicking the button once makes the code disappear, and then clicking it again makes the code re-appear. It seems like the function is doing the opposite of what I want it to do, but I have no idea why it's doing this: comparing my code to other code that does what I want it to do, I don't see any visible differences.

Here is the script:

```
<script>
        function showTweet() {
          var x = document.getElementById("tw-block-parent");

          if (x.style.display === "none") {
            x.style.display = "block";
          } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
          }
        }
        </script>
```

Here is the HTML that the script is supposed to make visible:

```
<div id="tw-block-parent">
        <div class="timeline-TweetList-tweet">
            <div class="timeline-Tweet">
                <div class="timeline-Tweet-brand">
                    <div class="Icon Icon--twitter"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-Tweet-author">
                    <div class="TweetAuthor"><a class="TweetAuthor-link" href="#channel"> </a><span class="TweetAuthor-avatar">
                        <div class="Avatar"> </div></span><span class="TweetAuthor-name">TwitterDev</span><span class="Icon Icon--verified"> </span><span class="TweetAuthor-screenName">@TwitterDev</span></div>
                    </div>
                    <!--This is where the tweet text goes-->
                    <div id="timeline-Tweet-text_1"></div>
                    <div class="timeline-Tweet-metadata"><span class="timeline-Tweet-timestamp">9h</span></div>
                    <ul class="timeline-Tweet-actions">
                        <li class="timeline-Tweet-action"><a class="Icon Icon--heart" href="#"></a></li>
                        <li class="timeline-Tweet-action"><a class="Icon Icon--share" href="#"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And finally here is the HTML button:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="onClick(); showTweet();" id="submit-button" class="instructions" value="try me!">
```

The 'OnClick();' function works fine as far as I know, but just in case I'll post it here too.

```
<script>
    //This function allows different inputs to display different text blocks
            function onClick() {
                if (document.getElementById("user_input").value === "I hate the EU!")
                {
                    antiEuropeExample();
                }
                else if (document.getElementById("user_input").value === "I hate traffic!")
                {
                        antiTrafficExample();
                }
                else if (document.getElementById("user_input").value === "I hate Trump!")
            {
                antiTrumpExample();
            }
                else if (document.getElementById("user_input").value === "I hate Facebook!")
                {
                        antiFacebookExample();
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Wrong input buddy!");
                }
            }

      </script>
```

I apologise for the amount of code I've posted here, I hope the question is understandable and that you guys can help! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All `<div>` elements have default styling `display:block;`, if you want to change the initial behavior of a particular element you have to add styling to it.

in your case i would advice changing this:

```
<div id="tw-block-parent">
```

to

```
<div id="tw-block-parent" style="display:none;">
```

This would make the div invisible at the start.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment! I'll give it a go today. Have a lovely weekend!

Comment: Putting 'style' into the HTML directly didn't work, but when I put display: none; into the CSS it worked. Thank you!